# Inserting current timestamp when editing a page in Dokuwiki

Tags: dokuwiki

Is it possible to insert the current timestamp while editing a page in Dokuwiki?

I am looking for some macro (for e.g. ~TIMESTAMP~), which will be replaced with the current timestamp when the page is saved (and NOT a command/plugin which fetches it *each* time the page is saved.

Answer (score 1):

There are several macros of this kind, but they are not directly available.

The page [namespace templates](http://www.dokuwiki.org/namespace_templates) describes how to set up namespace-level template files that automatically substitute some expressions (such as `@USER@` or `@DATE@`) when *creating* a new page in that directory. It should not be hard to adapt those to the format you desire.

Another choice would be adapt something from the [var plugin](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3avar) so that the instructions it generates are converted and saved as text during a page preview or save. It would require converting the plugin from a "syntax" plugin to an "action" plugin.